# Gdal_calc NDVI for many rasters

Tags: gdal, batch, map-algebra, gdal-calc

Can anybody help me to solve a problem with running gdal_calc for many rasters?

I have several multispectral images and I need a batch to perform NDVI calculation.

I started with gdal code for one raster and it works good:

`> C:\Python27\python.exe "C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\bin\gdal_calc.py" -A D:\my_dir\ras0_2.TIF --A_band=3 -B D:\my_dir\ras0_2.TIF --B_band=4 --outfile=D:\my_dir\ndvi.tif --calc=((B-A)/(B+A))`

But when I tried to run code for all TiFFs in a folder the program gave an error
"nonetype object has no attribute GetRasterBand"

`for %i in (*.tif) do C:\Python27\python.exe "C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\bin\gdal_calc.py" -A $i --A_band=3 -B $i --B_band=4 --calc="((B-A)/(B+A))" %i ndvi/ndvi_%i`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nearly there. Couple of small problems:

- You've used the bash syntax instead of cmd. i.e. `$` instead of `%`.
- Your `--outfile` parameter isn't specified explicitly, and looks a bit jumbled.

Try:

```
for %i in (*.tif) do C:\Python27\python.exe "C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\bin\gdal_calc.py" -A %i --A_band=3 -B %i --B_band=4 --calc="((B-A)/(B+A))" --outfile=ndvi_%i
```

If you have osgeo4w installed you can go open the osgeo4w shell, cd to the directory and run:

```
for %i in (*.tif) do gdal_calc -A %i --A_band=3 -B %i --B_band=4 --calc="((B-A)/(B+A))" --outfile=ndvi_%i
```

If you want a batch file to do this you'll need to use two percent signs before your variables - i.e. `%%i`

Comment: I've tested two scripts in my osgeo4w shell command line. The first one works fine, the operation is done, but I get the following error message : "Python has stopped working" after each processed TIF-file... When I use second script you recomended for osgeo4w (with *comp.tif) it don't work at all. Also I cleated a .bat file and tried to run it, but nothing happend.

Comment: Glad to help. the `comp` bit was just from my system. you want `*.tif`. I've amended my answer